# Disabled Checked checkbox shows as unchecked - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a input checkbox that is checked and disabled when some JS runs on page load.

```
<input name="selectUnionDues" id="selectUnionDues"  type="checkbox" checked="checked" runat="server" />
```

When I get the value of the checkbox by using (on the server side)

```
this.selectUnionDues.checked //returns false
```

I always get a false

**EDIT: I am concerned about using heavy asp.net controls since the page size in this application needs to be low. Is there a way out using HTMl controls?**

Comment: Here are the alternatives;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727974/how-to-post-submit-an-input-checkbox-that-is-disabled/60424933#60424933

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Disabled form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) are not "[successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)", that means they values aren't "submitted" at all with your form.

Answer (score 3):

check this out
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012506-1.aspx

In short, 
(1)there is a "SubmitDisabledControls" property of "form" or
(2)tweak the javascript the author provided

Comment: This doesn't always work; I was disabling tables-full of controls by the method suggested [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1121242/3109517.aspx) and it prevented `SubmitDisabledControls` from working properly. I had to disable all the controls in the table separately to get it to behave. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the checkbox, it always return false.
the best idea is to make the checkbox readonly, so that it will return the value as it is.
make the `readonly="readonly"`.

Comment: This MDN article specifically says to _not_ make checkboxes readonly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly

Answer (score 0):

I get less than intuitive behavior as well. If I test the value in Page_Init, it always returns true. Testing it in Page_Load returns the selected value.

Try using a server side control instead of an HTML control with runat=server.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="selectUnionDues" runat="server" Checked="true" />
```

Also, you state "disabled" control but I don't see anything that is disabled in your markup. Either way, better to use a server WebControl.

Comment: Between Page_Init and Page_Load there are more page lifecycle methods (which you can override if you want to): LoadViewState and LoadPostData. Both of these might change the values in the controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind relying on JS, you could have a hidden input who's value changes when the checkbox's check property changes and then use that value server side.

Comment: Btw, I'm guess it wouldn't be a problem relying on JS because JS is what is causing the checkbox to become disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Although the original question was about HtmlInputCheckBox control, I think it will be useful to mention that similar problem also exists for Checkbox control, for which the picture is more complicated, because there is a difference between Enabled="False" and disabled="disabled". I post results of the investigation here: [ASP.Net Checkbox.Checked is set to default when use disabled attribute or difference between Enabled property and disabled attribute](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.fi/2013/01/aspnet-checkboxchecked-is-set-to.html). Specifically it explains why Checked property is reset when disabled attribute is used, and why it is not reset when Enabled server property is used.