# How to add default value of this input? (This input is disabled)

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="is_ok" id="id_is_ok"/>
```

How to add default value of this input? (This input is disabled)

If this field in disabled If I edit my data, this value is not saved.

Comment: You can use `value="x"`, or is that not what you want?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you explain what exactly you want?

Comment: The value is always passed, it doesn't mind whether the checkbox's disabled or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727974/how-to-post-submit-an-input-checkbox-that-is-disabled

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the field is disabled, it is not send when the form is submitted.
If you want to have a field that cannot be edited but is submitted with the form, use `readonly="readonly"` instead.

**Edit**: Argh, this does not work, `readonly` is ignored for checkboxes, see comment below. Instead if you want to send that field value on submit, you can define a second hidden field with the same name and value:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="is_ok" />
<input type="hidden" name="is_ok" id="is_ok_hidden" value="some value here" />
```

(You can give that field a `value="some value here"` like any other html input field, and set that value via `element.setAttribute("value","some other value")` in JavaScript. As only value of the `type="hidden"` field is send, only set the value of that field and ignore the value for the checkbox.)

Comment: Uh, indeed you can change a `readonly` checkbox :( I have to admit that I never really tried until now. Seems the `readonly` attribute is ignored for checkboxes. Maybe you can still go the `disabled` way and send a hidden input field with it, like `<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="is_ok" value="value" /><input type="hidden"  name="is_ok" id="is_ok_hidden" value="value" />`. Quite a kludge, I have to admit.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="is_ok" value="bike" id="id_is_ok"/>
```

here bike is default value...

Comment: Ok. What if this input is disabled?