# Request.Form is nothing when the object is disabled

Tags: asp.net

I Google and search every article here and in the google but i cannot find anything regarding this issue. Any idea why the request.form["name here"] is nothing when the html control is disabled something like

```
<input  type="radio"  name="name here" disabled />
```

removing disabled would return the values. I tested this only on IE 10 not sure on other browsers.

I am looking into changing the css of the radio button but that is a different story.

Thank you.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: I edited my question. I posted the code. ty

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to POST/Submit an Input Checkbox that is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727974/how-to-post-submit-an-input-checkbox-that-is-disabled)

Comment: sorry missed that post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabled form fields are not part of the posted data. If you disable the html control the data will not be posted.

If you want to show the data and have it posted, but not possible to edit you can set the control to readonly instead.

```
<input  type="radio"  name="name here" readonly="readonly" />
```